# TRAMP and `projectile-ag`, `projectile-ripgrep` cause kernel panic and complete crash of Mac OS

Tags: osx, tramp, projectile, ag, ripgrep

I am using Emacs and TRAMP on a Mac to access a remote Git repo on a Linux machine. TRAMP is using the SSH protocol.

`projectile-find-file` and routine editing works great. Projectile finds the `.git` directory on the remote machine, through TRAMP.

`projectile-ag`, `projectile-ripgrep` and I think `projectile-grep` *sometimes* work, but other times cause a complete crash of the Mac. I presume some limit is exceeded for number of connections or remote buffers, and the kernel panics. Perhaps the calls to `ag` happen too quickly over the network? Perhaps a delay needs to be used between calls to `ag`?

The `ag` and `rg` executables are on the Mac, not on the remote machine. I would prefer not to install these on the remote machine.

This kernel panic never occurs with `projectile-ag` and a local repository, without TRAMP.

I don't have any log information to share but have sent the reports to Apple when the system reboots.

Emacs 28.1 and current TRAMP version

Thanks for any ideas

---

It occurs after this message:

```
Tramp: Sending command ‘
  exec ssh -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C'
    -o ControlPersist=no -e none [domain name of box]’
```

Answer (score 1):

I can’t help you with your crash, but when editing files via TRAMP, you must run tools like `ag` and `rg` via TRAMP as well. They must be installed on the remote machine to work. Since they’re not part of Emacs, they have no idea how to read the content of remote files the way Emacs does.

Comment: Thanks, it also happens with `projectile-grep`. `grep` is definitely available on the remote machine. I hear the fans on the Macbook spin way up before it restarts. This implies heavy CPU usage, perhaps TRAMP is stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: It could be a similar issue to this: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1000